# Cypress tests not running. Error - node-cachedir

Tags: cypress

I am trying to run cypress from my application (to be tested) code. I am getting below error:

> Uncaught Error: Your OS "browser" is currently not supported by node-cachedir.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what kind of browser are you using? Note that only Chrome, Chromium and Electron are supported browsers at this moment

Comment: I am using Chrome only. I can run cypress easily if it is installed in empty directory.
I am getting this issue when I installed cypress into web application directory.

Comment: Check, searching the github of Cypress brings me to this possible solution: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1239#issuecomment-362363993